# Create dropdown list by capturing nonblank values from a column

Tags: excel, validation, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown list that will capture from a column but the column has some blanks, is there a way to ignore the blanks?

Also, if possible can I just capture take every other cell in that column in my dropdown list?

This list that I can capturing from is also on another worksheet.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy column to other sheet, sort it and you have list without blanks (they are on the end of list in column).

Comment: Haha the only problem is that the list is ever growing depends if the user wants to input more values on the first sheet. =/

Comment: hm.... maybe you can do sql query (in vba) to that column and in where condition you put lenght(column) >0 . This must start when sheet change....